# Union of Banach Spaces

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces

Consider a family of Banach spaces $(V_n,|\cdot|_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $V_1 \subseteq V_2 \subseteq V_3\subseteq ...$ and $n\le m \Rightarrow |f|_m \le |f|_n \forall f \in V_n$. Is there a natural topology on $V = \bigcup\limits_{n = 1}^\infty V_n$ ?

Comment: Is there an example of such a family you could reference? I wonder if the space of $C^n$ functions might apply, except that such a space $C^{\infty}$ in the limiting case is not normable, though still admits a topology. The convergence of continuously weaker topologies to a new topology is interesting.

Comment: The [direct limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit)

Comment: @askquestions2 Actually $C^\infty=\bigcap C^n$, not $\bigcup C^n$...

Comment: Do you really mean $<$? I guess you mean $\leq$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guided by the comment of user85667, I looked for direct limits in the context of Banach spaces and found out that the construction I am looking for is known as [LB-Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LB-space).